# useState didn't seem to work with socket io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, message, use-effect

I'm making a message feature with socket.io.
When I send/receive a message, I want to change the state of `newMsgNO`, but it doesn't seem to work.
In the second `useEffect` below, first `console.log` always show the initial state that `newMsgNO:  0`, while second `console.log` shows the value of `newMessages.current` well whenever they come in.

This is one of what I tried to. In the `testMessage` below I tried to change the state, and component was rendered again with new message. But the state of `newMsgNO` was the `0` too. and I should not do like that because that works only when I sending the message. I should do work in the code of `socket.on("new message", ...)`.

How can I change the state of `newMsgNO` in `socket.on("new message", ...)` ?

```
...

 const newMessages = useRef([
    {
      userImg: "",
      userName: "",
      talkContent: "",
      talkTime: "",
      isContinuous: false,
    },
  ]);

  const [newMsgNO, countNewMsg] = useState(0);

  const testReceiveM = {
    userImg: "",
    userName: "ab",
    talkContent: "hello my name is...",
    talkTime: "22.03.04.12:22",
    isContinuous: false,
  };

  const testMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("send message", { roomId, msg: testReceiveM });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("join room", roomId);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("new message", (currentMsg: NewMessage) => {

      if (newMessages.current.length === 1 && !newMessages.current[0].userName) {
        newMessages.current = [currentMsg];

        countNewMsg(newMsgNO + 1);

      } else {
        newMessages.current.push(currentMsg);

        countNewMsg(newMsgNO + 1);

      }

      countNewMsg(newMsgNO + 1);

      console.log("newMsgNO: ", newMsgNO);
      console.log("newMessages.current: ", newMessages.current);

    });
  }, []);

  return (

        ...

      {newMsgNO > 0 &&
        newMessages.current.map((_, idx) => (
          <MessageRecord key={_.userName + idx.toString} message={_} />
        ))}

      <button onClick={testMessage}>testMessage</button>

       ...
  );
```

Comment: The code about the second  paragraph "This is one of what I tried to.  ..." is not in the question code! It is just what I tried to.

Answer (score 0):

I got this! Thanks to "뚜아아아" from open chat room in frontend development.

`countNewMsg((prev) => prev + 1);` this is all about this.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("new message", (currentMsg: NewMessage) => {

      if (newMessages.current.length === 1 && !newMessages.current[0].userName) {
        newMessages.current = [currentMsg];
      } else {
        newMessages.current.push(currentMsg);
      }

      countNewMsg((prev) => prev + 1);

      console.log("newMsgNO: ", newMsgNO);
      console.log("newMessages.current: ", newMessages.current);

    });
  }, []);
```

Because of asynchronous logic, my previous try didn't work.
So I made it work like synchronous design. `(prev) => prev + 1`

And when `setState` is set many times, only the last one works.
So I deleted them on if condition. Because they were for test and now they are not necessary, it is not required to do additional work about it.

I'm so glad to solve this.
Goodnight everyone!